How to optimized an initialization of mutation in mapping
How to optimize this kind of code that every movie has its own initialization of mutation.
I know I should put the initialization of mutation on the top of the file of MoviesPage, but that's not the only page I have movies and I have a lot of mutation like, add to watch list and something else.
export default async function MoviesPage() {
  const movies = await getMovies() // 100 movies
  return (
    <div>
      {movies.map(movie => (
        <Movie key={movie.id} movie={movie} />
      ))}
    </div>
  )
}

// Movie Component
import { useMutation } from '@tanstack/react-query'


function Movie(movie: TMovie) {
  const { mutate } = useMutation({mutationFn:()=> ...})

  return (
    <div onClick={() => mutate(movie)}>
      <image src={movie.posterPath} />
    </div>
  )
}


If I get it right, your code is already ok since Movie component will be created for each movie in your list and each Movie component will run useMutation hook with its own mutationFn.
I dare to suggest you wanted to incapsulate your mutations to one single place to reuse it in different components? If so, you need to create a custom hook which will contain all your business logic and all your actions upon movies:
import { useMutation } from '@tanstack/react-query';

const useMovieActions = (movie) => {
    const { mutate: update } = useMutation({
        mutationFn: (updatedMovie) => axios.post(`/movies/${movie.id}`, updatedMovie)
    });

    const { mutate: addToWatchList } = useMutation({
        mutationFn: () => axios.post(`/watch-list`, movie.id)
    });

    const { mutate: like } = useMutation({
        mutationFn: () => axios.post(`/likes`, movie.id)
    });

    return {
        update,
        addToWatchList,
        like,
    }
};

and then use it in your components like this:
function Movie(movie: TMovie) {
    const { update, like, addToWatchList } = useMovieActions(moview)

    return (
        <div onClick={() => update(movie)}>
            <image src={movie.posterPath}/>
            <button onClick={like()}>Like</button>
            <button onClick={addToWatchList()}>Add to watch list</button>
        </div>
    )
}

This way your components don't know about how your api looks like and how to convert business actions to api, so this is always a good practise to hide it from your components and leave to them only rendering and to handle user interactions.

I will probably use this, but my concern is does  initialization of useMutation() not duplicate in each movie. What if I implement an Infinite Scroll and the movies length goes 1000, does this mean the useMutation initialized 1000 times? idk how it works under the hood and how to know it.

It is ok. Every hook, every component is called as many times as you call setState (useState hook). It is nature of React.
